# Пять процентов населения одобряет. Или одобряют?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, единственное-множественное-число

Пять процентов населения *одобряет* или *одобряют*?
Как правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Население, конечно же, *одобряет*.
А вот счетный оборот *пять процентов населения* может иметь сказуемое как в единственном, так и во множественном числе.

Если бы при счетном обороте имелись слова ***все, эти*** или другие в роли определения, то сказуемое ставилось бы во множественном числе, например:
***Эти** пять процентов населения **одобряют**...*

Если бы в составе подлежащего наличествовали слова ***всего, лишь, только*** (со значением ограничения), то сказуемое бы ставилось в единственном числе, например:
***Только** пять процентов населения **одобряет**...*

Если бы имелся причастный оборот или определительное придаточное предложение с союзным словом ***который***, причем причастие или слово *который* стояло бы во множественном числе, то сказумое бы тоже имело множественное число, например:

*Пять процентов населения, **сумевшие** «сесть» на сырьевые и финансовые потоки, **образуют** привилегированный экономически господствующий класс* (Г. А. Явлинский).

*Население* (собирательное существительное) — это совокупность людей, проживающих где-либо, в каком-либо месте (на земном шаре, в каком-либо государстве, в какой-либо стране, области и т. п.).

Какой-либо процент населения — это тоже совокупность людей, которую опрашивали. Но ведь каждого отдельно, не группой, не скопом — то есть множественное число.
Думаю, что оно предпочтительней.

В анкетах, розданных фашистами, девяносто пять процентов населения **ответили** ― кто по-немецки, кто по-французски, а больше на запрещенном летцебургеш, ― что национальность, и подданство, и родной их язык были и будут люксембургскими. [В. Дружинин. Упорный маленький Люксембург // «Вокруг света», 1968]

По данным социологических исследований, в Москве уже целых пять процентов населения **владеют** домашними кинотеатрами. [Юрий Мамаев. Сегмент превращается в рынок (2002) // «Дело» (Самара), 10.06.2002]

[Сказуемое при подлежащем — количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте)](http://rozental.gramatik.ru/xliii-soglasovanie-skazuemogo-s-podlezhashchim/ss-184-skazuemoe-pri-podlezhashchem-kolichestvenno-imennom-sochetanii-schetnom-oborote)

Answer (score 0):

С одной стороны, правильно будет «Пять процентов населения одобряет»: сказуемое ставится в единственном числе, если собирательное существительное имеет при себе управляемое слово в родительном падеже единственного числа, например: *«Подавляющее большинство населения пришло на избирательные участки»*.

Но с другой стороны, есть работа [Ю. М. Кувшинской](https://studiorum.ruscorpora.ru/stylistics/syntax_percent/) из Образовательного портала Национального корпуса русского языка на тему согласования сказуемого со счетным оборотом, содержащим проценты. Скопирую выводы: в предложениях с подлежащим, выраженным счетным оборотом и включающим слово проценты, сказуемое **преимущественно** стоит во множественном числе. Таким образом, предпочтительным оказывается **согласование по смыслу**.

Рекомендую ознакомиться с этой работой полностью, чтобы увидеть все нюансы.

---

Кстати, при количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте) сказуемое тоже может иметь как форму единственного, так и форму множественного числа:

1. *Вошло семь человек погони...* (Лесков).
2. *– Наутро пятьдесят семь выходцев подали заявления с просьбой принять в колхоз* (Шолохов).

Вот [по этой ссылке](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/70091268.html) более подробно.

Comment: Кажется мне, что рассуждения ваши неправильны. У нас здесь имеется только одно собирательное существительное — *население*.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова дополнил ответ выводами из статьи Ю. М. Кувшинской с Образовательного портала Национального корпуса русского языка (как раз по вопросу процентов).